# How do I print a character multiple times by a user input number?

Tags: python

My friend and I recently started learning python and we have a task that the both of us are struggling with. The task involves getting a number from the user and printing that many underscores. Example: user entered 8, the the code will print 8 underscores in one line. My code is

```
num = input('Enter a number: ')
```

after that, to make it print the underscores I thought it would be something like

```
print('_'*num)
```

I tried many variations of that and suggestions from the internet but I still can't get it to work without a syntax error. My friend and I are both very stuck on this, any help appreciated. Feel free to ask questions, I found this hard to explain since I'm new to this.

Comment: Please include the full error messages and add a tag python-3.x or python-2.7, depending on which version of Python you use. Most likely you use 3.x and `input` returns a string, not a number.

Comment: `input()` returns a string. Try converting it to an `int`.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Thank You for posting the question. If you think one of the answer met your need, click the check mark. it will close the thread. It will also help you to acknowledge the contributors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of the responses here are way too complex for a very simple problem. The only issue with your code is that `num` is a string, not an integer. You cannot multiply two strings, thus this will throw `TypeError: can't multiple sequence by non-int of type 'str'`. The fix is simple, change the type:

```py
num = input('Enter a number: ')
print("_" * int(num))
```

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the issue is you need to use `int(input("Enter a number: "))` instead of just `input`, to convert the input from a string to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the input to an integer

```
num = int(input("Number"))
"_______________________________"[:num] # substring
"".join(["_" for i in range(num)]) # build array then construct string
"_"*num # string repetition
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = int(input("enter: "))
```

this is inputting the number of times you want the unerscore to be printed.

```
for i in range(num):
```

this for loop repeats the code inside n times

```
print("_", end =" ")
```

The end =" " makes sure that the next print statement happens on the same line, so the final code would be:

```
num = int(input("enter: "))
for i in range(num):
   print("_", end =" ")
```

Hope this helps! (It's my first time answering lol)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
i = input("Enter the number: ")  # get input from user
character = "_"
for x in range(int(i)):
    print(character, end="")  # repeat print the specified character. end="" ensurer that all is in one line
```

Answer (score -1):

`for i in (0, userinput): print('hello world', end = ')`
end = is for no newline

Comment: This will break. `range()` does not accept strings as arguments and will throw `TypeError`.